# Using memcpy to copy a structure into the heap

Tags: c, struct, memcpy

I am trying to put a structure named "Holder" into the heap by using the following code, but I get a segmentation fault when I try to use memcpy:

```
Holder hold;
Holder *heapHold = memcpy(heapHold, &hold, sizeof(Holder));
```

Why do I segfault?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Holder hold;
```

This declares `hold` as a variable of type `Holder`.  `hold` is uninitialized.

```
Holder *heapHold = memcpy(heapHold, &hold, sizeof(Holder));
```

`memcpy(dest, source, size)` copies `size` bytes from `source` to `dest`.  It assumes that `dest` is properly allocated.  Since you don't allocate memory for it, you get a segfault.

You need to allocate memory:

```
Holder *heapHold = malloc(sizeof *heapHold);
if (heapHold == NULL) {
    /* failed to allocate, handle error here */
} else {
    /* OK to copy.  Make sure you initialize 'hold' to something valid */
    memcpy(heapHold, &hold, sizeof *heapHold);
}
```

Also, `memcpy()` returns the first parameter.  Assigning the return value to `heapHold` is just like saying `a = a;`, i.e., it doesn't do anything.  For most practical cases, the return value of `memcpy()` is ignored.

Comment: This still assumes that it is valid to copy `Holder` instances with `memcpy` in the first place. Granted, in C this is *normally* the case...

Comment: @Karl, can you give me an example of an instance where `&holder` cannot be copied?

Comment: Structures which contain pointers to (within) themselves, or which contain pointers to data that should be deep-copied.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for `heapHold` first. Currently memcpy is writing to some random address (`heapHold` is uninitialized), causing the crash.

```
Holder hold;
Holder *heapHold = malloc(sizeof(Holder));
memcpy(heapHold, &hold, sizeof(Holder));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Holder hold;
Holder *heapHold = malloc(sizeof(Holder));
memcpy(heapHold,&hold,sizeof(Holder));
```

The `heapHold` variable in `memcpy(heapHold, &hold, sizeof(Holder));` is still not initialized (and no buffer was allocated what-so-ever) so it's pointing to invalid memory.

BTW (I always forget to mention that) - when you allocate memory using `malloc`, don't `forget` to free it later..